# Derivation of fourier series equation

Tags: fourier-series

No matter where I search, every time if there's an article about Fourier series derivation, the first step made by author is to present the following formula:

$$f(x) = \frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(a_n \cos(\frac{2\pi}{T}nx) + b_n \sin(\frac{2\pi}{T}nx)\right)$$

Then, given that formula, the coefficients $a_n$ and $b_n$ are derived. My question is, how did Fourier come up with this main equation? Was it just a lucky guess? It could have been, because there are various proofs showing that the formula is true.

[Here](http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Fourier/Series/DerFS.html) the main equation just appears there without justification, just like formulas for even and odd cases below. It's really hard to call the article a derivation in my opinion.

Comment: This follows from general Hilbert space theory, see for example https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/book/ch6.pdf Theorem 6.26 (just a random google hit). The equation is an application of that theorem with the Hilbert Space being $L^{2}(\mathbb{T})$ and the functions $ \{\sin(nx): n \in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{\cos(nx): n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ being the orthogonal basis. Note that the convergence is generally not pointwise, but meant in terms of the norm of the respective Hilbert Space.

Comment: This answer may help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364304/fourier-analysis/364371#364371

Answer (score 3):

This answer is mostly for students who used an algebra approach. I don't know if Fourier himself thought up the series this way, but it is common today. I left a lot of steps out and mainly showed ideas that I struggled with when I first tried to motivate the Fourier Series.

I'll start off by observing a trigonometric polynomial:

$T(x) = c_0 + c_1 \cos(x) + c_2 \cos(2x)+...+c_n \cos(n x) + d_1 \sin(x) + ... + d_n \sin(n x)$

where $c_n$ and $d_n$ are some non-zero value.
The goal is write the orthogonal basis, from there I can find the coefficients.
So, I need declare the inner product:
$<\textbf{f},\textbf{g}> = \int_0^{2\pi} f(x)g(x)dx$

Before I can obtain a orthogonal basis, I should first get the orthonormal basis by using the Gram–Schmidt process. Where $\|\textbf{g}_0\| = \|\textbf{g}_1\| =\|\textbf{g}_2\| = ... =\|\textbf{g}_n\| = 1$.

$\|\textbf{f}\|^2 = <\textbf{f}><\textbf{f}> = 2\pi$

Thus, $\|\textbf{f}\| = \sqrt{2\pi}$

and

$e_0 = \frac{\textbf{f}}{\|\textbf{f}\|}$

$\textbf{g}_0 = e_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$

$\textbf{g}_1 = e_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\cos(x)$
...

$\textbf{g}_n = e_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\cos(nx)$...

$\textbf{g}_{n+1} = e_{n+1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sin((n+1)x)$...

$\textbf{g}_{2n} = e_{2n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sin(nx)$

The orthogonal basis yields:

$a_0 = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}<\textbf{f},\textbf{g}_0>$   (Use 2 because it makes generalizing the coefficients possible.)

$a_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}<\textbf{f},\textbf{g}_1>$...

$a_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}<\textbf{f},\textbf{g}_n>$...

$b_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}<\textbf{f},\textbf{g}_{2n}>$

Now that everything is divided into sines and cosines I can get the coefficients:

$a_n = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(x)\cos(nx)dx $

and

$b_n = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(x)\sin(nx)dx $

Answer (score 1):

You will agree that the functions
$$x\mapsto\cos(\lambda x),\qquad \lambda>0,$$
and their translates are the "purest", "simplest", "most beautiful", etc., periodic functions you can think of. They are the solutions of the "super simple" ODE $$y''+\lambda^2\>y=0$$ for given $\lambda>0$.

Among all these functions solely the functions
$$x\mapsto\cos\left({2n\pi \over T}x\right)$$
and their translates have the prescribed period $T$. It follows that the most general functions that can be built linearly from such pure periodic functions of period $T$ are the functions specified in your question.

Herewith the following grand problem arises: Can *every* $T$-periodic function $g$ be written in this form, or will after the best conceivable approximation of $g$ by series of this type remain some "nonharmonic remainder"? That the latter is not the case is the essential content of the theory of Fourier series.